# GOlang/https: timeout waiting for client preface

Tags: ssl, go, https, http2

I switched SSL by using `ListenAndServeTLS`

```
    func main() {
        serverMux := http.NewServeMux()
        serverMux.HandleFunc("/v1/ws1", handler1) 
        serverMux.HandleFunc("/v1/ws2", handler2)
        serverMux.HandleFunc("/v1/ws3", handler3) 
        serverMux.HandleFunc("/static/", handlerStatic(http.FileServer(http.Dir("/var/project/"))))
        go func() {
            wsSSLServer := &http.Server{
                Addr:         ":443",
                Handler:      serverMux,
                ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
                WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
            }
            certPath := "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/"
            fmt.Println(wsSSLServer.ListenAndServeTLS(certPath+"fullchain.pem", certPath+"privkey.pem"))
        }()
        wsServer := &http.Server{
            Addr:         ":80",
            Handler:      serverMux,
            ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
            WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
        }
        fmt.Println(wsServer.ListenAndServe())
    }
```

and now I get lots of these errors in the logs:

> http2: server: error reading preface from client x.x.x.x:xxxxx:
>   timeout waiting for client preface

what does it mean?

Comment: Is your client actually sending an https request?

Comment: yes, currently serving both http and https

Comment: Sorry Daniele, my question was is your *client* sending a valid http2 request? The server waits 10 seconds for the client to send the preface then gives up.

Comment: The client is typically a mobile browser like Chrome for Android, which simply visits the https:// URL

Comment: over https:// I am actually serving an HTML page generated by Go. Any idea of what's happening?

Comment: Unfortunately no, not without more context. Sorry, I wish I could help.

Comment: I have this problem as well, have you found a solution? I use Firefox as the client.

Comment: @Janek, unfortunately I haven't found neither an explanation nor a solution

Comment: Can you please post a minimal example of code that is producing this error?

Comment: @voutasaurus I added the code

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using Firefox as the client. **Regenerating the SSL key/cert solved the issue**, I guess the certificate expired.

For localhost development:

`openssl req -nodes -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days XXX -subj '/CN=localhost'`